# Dll usage by .NET application

Tags: c#, .net, dll, appdomain

Have a question for `.NET` experts.

I have a set of `WinForms applications` which uses some subset of dll's (some of them are shared between those apps). All binaries resides in the same directory. I need to split those WinForms apps and take only dll's which are needed by concrete app. How can I easily do that (need fast "5-min" solution)?

Options I considered:

1. domain.ExecuteAssembly(@"exefilename");
   domain.GetAssemblies(); //to determine what assemblies are used by the app.

   Needs single thread apartment attribute or a separate thread.
   Has issues with x86, x64 and AnyCPU builds.
   A lot of tricks with security, framework versions and so on.

   So, I think this is not a "5 min" solution and needs some additional investigation.
2. Assembly.GetReferencedAssemblies()

   Has 1 level limitation (doesn't work when assembly references assembly which in turn references another assembly).
   Does not work for raw assembly loading (when you read it from the file and load by AppDomain.Load Method (Byte[], Byte[]))
3. Process.Modules (from System.Diagnostics)

   Doesn't work for starting from .NET 4 (it is a bug on msft connect entered for this issue). Would be great "5min" solution for .NET 3.5, but I need a solution for .NET 4.5.
4. Just execute the app and delete every dll in the folder. Those are used will not be deleted (file will be locked out). But still, doesn't work for raw assembly loading.

Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: You only created the Windows Forms, Depends up on the Module like 1) User Action -> signIn,SignUP, forgotPassword, Reset Password 2) DB Inser/ADd/Edit ,4) DB DEleted Form appln like that you can split

Comment: There is a nice article here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163641.aspx#S1 if you decide to go with option 1.

Comment: @Akshay Joy Sorry, not sure I'm following you. In dll's resides some business logic, not necessary UI. But I need to know which subset of those dll's is used by the every single app in particular.

Comment: @MarianZagoruiko- You can check the METADATA by using Reflcetion to see the DLL dependecy

Comment: @AkshayJoy I need some programmatic solution (it's an important requirement).

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, [IlDasm.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa309387(v=vs.71).aspx) recursively checks DLL dependencies for you.